# Can't see my old /Home

Tags: home-directory

i had ubuntu 12.04 installed with separeted home, i have reinstalled it due to an error of my graphic card, and i choose to format the partition with ubuntu with ext4, and for the home partition i choose "use this partition" "ext4" BUT "DON'T format this partition"

Now if i go in "file system>home i can see my old directory with my files, but when i go in the Home folder directly from the dash i enter in a new empty home....how can i merge this 2 home?

Comment: Please post the paths of both homes (Ctrl+L shows the path of the directory you're in), the one with all your old files and the one you get when you open your home directory through the dash.

Comment: The one wich i see when enter from the dash is this /home/roberto

The old one with my files are this /home/obit8

The user name is changed...is the only thing i can see :)

Comment: Okay then just use the answer below ^^

Answer (score 0):

You have created another user. 
If the home folder are not encrypted, just copy your files from the old user.

Comment: I've copyed all files, now i'm trying to delete the old "home" but inside i have a thuderbird folder that doesn't allow me to modify or delete the folder!

Comment: I will tell howto remove it, but before that, make sure everything is working fine ;-)

Comment: Yes it seems is all good, the only thing i have in the old home is thunderbird folder...and i want remove it also because i'm trying to install thunderbird in italian and i can't!!!!

Comment: This shouldn't be keeping you to install the Italian version. To remove: go to system settings > user then make sure you are at admin user. Then remove the other user if it exists. Then open a terminal type "gksu nautilus" and you will be able to delete. Make a backup ;-)